# Removing a timestamp with a JS regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, timestamp

So I'm beginner with js and regexps are a sore spot for me.  I need to remove a timestamp from my dropdowns. Here is how it appears:

```
<option value="Aqua">
  <span>Aqua - Available to ship 2013-05-29 01:02:00.0 - $18.00</span>
</option>
```

I have an `if` statement appending the Available to ship text and the date at the end. Essentially the only think I need to grab is the date. So I'm thinking I could either just chop off everything after the date or remove the timestamp with a regex. The issue is I'm having a lot of trouble getting either of these to work.  Here is my if statement.

```
if ((index == selectors.length || (selectors.length > 1 && key !== 'color')) && product.availability.online.fulfillment != null) {
        var date = product.availability.online.fulfillment
        value.text = product.options[key] + ' - Available to ship ' + date + ' - $' + product.price.value;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove:

```
date = date.substring(0, date.indexOf(' '));
```

Regex replace:

```
date = date.replace(/[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]/, '');
```